# herança dinâmica de value de um input para os filhos (lista não ordenada)

Tags: jquery, html5

olá, preciso de alguma ideia de como criar uma herança dinâmica dos valores de um input pai para os input filhos e netos. Assim que o usuário digitar o valor em um input automaticamente ele precisa ser alterado nos itens filhos. baseado em um atributo do input chamado "herdar" que recebe o id do input do qual ele vai herdar o valor.

O esquema que criei não da certo, ele atualiza todos.

```js
 
$('input:text').change(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   if (($(this).parent().find('input:text').attr('herdar')) == id) {
       $(this).parent().find('input:text').val(id);
   }
});
```

```html
<div id="teste1">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="00" checked="true"><input type="text" >teste
        
             <ul>
                 <li> <input type="checkbox" value="01"><input type="text" >item pai
                    <ul>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="01"><input type="text" >item filho</li>
                        <li><input type="checkbox" value="01"><input type="text" >item filho</li>  
                   </ul>
                </li>
               <li><input type="checkbox" value="04"><input type="text" >item irmão</li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Eu fiz com Jquery, mas se alguém tiver uma ideia mais simples e melhor tudo bem.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isto era o que queria:

Escreva algo no primeiro `input`.

```js
$('input:text').keyup(function(){
 var id= $(this).attr('id');
  $('input[data-herdar="' + id + '"]').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="teste1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" value="00" checked="true">
      <input type="text" id="pai" >teste
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" value="01">
          <input type="text">item pai
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="01">
              <input type="text">item filho</li>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" value="01">
              <input type="text" data-herdar="pai" ><b><em>Este input herdará do primeiro</em>   </b></li> 
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" value="04">
          <input type="text">item irmão</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Como no exemplo acima, você define o `id` do elemento que será herdado, e no elemento que o herdará se adiciona o atributo `data-herdar`, que receberá este `id` do elemento herdado.
Pronto, o `script` faz o resto.

Obs.: sempre que quizer trabalhar co a manipulação de novos tributos, em geral, usa-se o prefixo `data-`, assim não há conflitos, além de ser uma especificação "universal".

Answer (score 0):

Basta adicionar no `if` a condição para ignorar o próprio elemento sendo alterado.

PS: Você estava executando o mesmo selector 3 vezes, isso tem um custo desnecessário pro navegador, guardei o resultado desse selector dentro de uma variável para buscar apenas uma vez, assim melhora a performance.

```
$('input:text').change(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');

   var filho = $(this).parent().find('input:text');

   if (filho.attr('herdar') == id && filho.prop('id') != id) {
       filho.val(id);
   }
});
```